# Doxygen documenting commented #define

Tags: c++, documentation, comments, doxygen, c-preprocessor

I'm new to Doxygen and recently run into a problem which I could not solve.
I have this piece of documented code:

```
/*!
    \def nAsserts
    Uncomment that line so that all asserts would be removed
*/
//#define nAsserts
```

and it's supposed to tell the user to uncomment that line when they wish to remove all asserts but doxygen is returning me a warning:

> warning: documentation for unknown define nAsserts found

I think the problem is that doxygen ignores all commented codes so is that any way to fix this or work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it is a best option, but you can use the approach below.

Modify configuration file to include `PREDEFINED` parameter:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION      = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF   = YES
PREDEFINED           = "DOXYGEN=1"
```

In your code, do the following:

```
#if DOXYGEN
#define nAsserts
#endif
```

Doxygen follows own preprocessor and can conditionally include/exclude source module sections.

Comment: hey thanks now nAsserts shows up in the documentation but it doesn't have the line number attached like how a normal define does anyway to solve that?

Comment: Hey turns out the problem was on my part. Thanks for the solution it's working perfectly now. Cheers.